# Winforms Inhereted Control preventing the designer from working

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 forms that inherit a control from the class below:

```
public class AInbox: Form
{
    public FlowLayoutPanel InboxItems;
}
```

The forms inherits as such:

```
public partial class Inbox : AInbox
{
...
}
```

In the Designer.cs file i commented out the original "InboxItems" control declaration and everything compiles and runs fine... except the GUI designer. When i open the Designer I get the error "The variable 'InboxItems' is either undeclared or was never assigned."

Is there any way to use this inheritance and still have the designer work?

Comment: _I commented out the original "InboxItems" control declaration"_: Can I ask why you commented it out?  Presumably the desginer partial class utilises it when laying out the form and this is causing your error

Comment: Winforms calls in the constructor a method called `InitializeComponent` where it calls to the constructors of the elements, subscribes to events, etc. Is your child class calling parent constructor?

Comment: I commented out the declaration (not the constructor, ```//public System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel InboxItems;```) as this was overriding the inherited control which meant the inherited control was just null when i tried to access it.

Comment: "this was overriding the inherited control which meant the inherited control was just null when i tried to access it. " The control was `null` because you never instantiated it in the parent class and not because of overriding, especially because I don't see any `override` keyword in your code. The parent constructor will be called before the child constructor. So if the parent does not do `... = new ...` the child will get nothing

Comment: Apologies, override was the wrong word... it was "hiding" the inherited member. The parent class just contains the declaration, while the form designer has the constructor and all the other instantiation code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend against inheriting a form with generated code (like you're doing with Inbox).

If you want the child class (Inbox) to add additional controls, I wouldn't use the designer directly on the child class, because I don't think the visual studio form designer will play nicely when half of the form was designed in the parent class. If you need to reuse certain parts of your form in a different form, you might want to consider moving that part of the form to a separate user control. You can use the designer on this user control and later put the user control in the forms.

If you just need to have the same form, keep an instance of the form in your other class. Move your logic away from your form (view) and in your other class (controller).

Comment: Ahh, so basically i'm doing it backwards by having a small parent and large child. I should have the majority of the design in the parent and minor things in the child.